# Confusion on DNS having site hosted somewhere with email elsewhere

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server

I have read several old posts on here but I am still nervous and want someones insight before changing the DNS for physical website hosting, but I want to keep the email hosting as is.  I have a customer that currently has their DNS managed through PowerYourName.com

The email services are hosted through PowerYourName.com

Their website is hosted at Weebly, but I am switching it to Godaddy.

I don't want to mess up the email and I want the email to remain with PowerYourName.com.. .

I attached a screenshot of the DNS.  Do I just change the www. A record and the @ A record to the IP address for Godaddy's hosting?

Sorry, I am such a novice that I don't want to mess this up because it is a lawyers website with a lot of important emails.  [Picture of DNS here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08thc.jpg)

Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

Your `www` A record and your `@` A record are used for http://www./ and http://

For email you need the `@` MX record which I cannot see. So I suggest you do a `dig @8.8.8.8 <domain> MX` to find out what the MX record points to.

If the MX record point to a completely different A record than the two used for your web server, then it's safe to change the two A records for the web server. If the A record referenced to by the MX record is one of those two used by the web server, it's not so easy to migrate.